# dplyr::anti_join unexpected results

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large tibble, call it `df`, and using `dplyr::filter` I have filtered it down to a smaller tibble, call it `df_filter`. I want to see a tibble of the rows that have been filtered out, so I did `df_exclude <- df %>% anti_join(df_filter)`. The original tibble has no duplicate rows, so I thought that `bind_rows(df_filter, df_exclude)` should be identical to `df`.

However, when I run `identical(df, bind_rows(df_filter, df_exclude))` I get `FALSE`. I have checked that `nrow(df_filter) + nrow(df_exclude) == nrow(df)` returns `TRUE`, so at least the number of rows is correct.

There are some `NA` entries in the original tibble - could this be causing `identical` to return `FALSE`? If so, how do I check that the two tibbles are equal?

Comment: `bind_rows(df_filter, df_exclude)` puts all the filter rows first followed by all the exclude rows, which is probably a different order than the rows are in `df`, so it won't be identical. Try sorting on an ID column or something to make sure they are in the same order.

Comment: Or, don't use identical. Use something like `setdiff(df, bind_rows(df_filter, df_exclude))` and `setdiff(bind_rows(df_filter, df_exclude), df)`. Both setdiffs should be empty.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks, I didn't realize `identical` cares about the order of the rows. When I sort both it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: 1:3 is not identical to 3:1!